# How to convert Date & Time into specific range in PHP

Tags: php

I have following php dates for example:

```
2018-07-16 02:07:30
2018-07-16 02:17:30
2018-07-16 02:37:30
2018-07-16 02:47:30
```

I have to convert above dates in to below dates grammatically:

```
2018-07-16 02:15:00
2018-07-16 02:30:00
2018-07-16 02:45:00
2018-07-16 03:00:00
```

e.g If minute is 1-15 It should be 15, If minutes is 16-30 It should be 30, If minutes is 31-45 It should be 45, and If minutes is 46-60 It should be 00.

Comment: And what have you already tried to solve your coding problem?

Comment: I have't idea about this.

Comment: Iterate over each row, create datetime from format, output in new format. Pretty basic.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari what do you need on exit (String or DateTime object)?

Comment: Datetime e.g 2018-07-16 02:15:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should get the `timestring` from the date, then set fraction 900 (seconds) which is equal to 15 minutes. You can [Convert 900 Seconds to Minutes](https://www.calculateme.com/time/seconds/to-minutes/900), then get the `timestring_fraction` by `$timestring_fraction = $timestring % $fraction;` and calculate minutes and create a new date by doing this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $minutes)`.

**Code**

```
$date = '2018-07-16 02:37:30';
$timestring = strtotime($date);

// 900 seconds which is equal to 15 minutes
$fraction = 900;
$timestring_fraction = $timestring % $fraction;

$minutes = $timestring + ($fraction - $timestring_fraction);
$updated_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $minutes);

echo $updated_date;
```

**Output**

```
// 2018-07-16 02:07:30
2018-07-16 02:15:00

// 2018-07-16 02:17:30
2018-07-16 02:30:00

// 2018-07-16 02:37:30
2018-07-16 02:45:00

// 2018-07-16 02:47:30
2018-07-16 03:00:00
```

## Updated Answer

What if the time is something like this `2018-07-16 02:30:00` then the solution will be

```
$timestring_fraction = $timestring % $fraction;

if ($timestring_fraction === 0) {
    echo $date;
}
else {
    $minutes = $timestring + ($fraction - $timestring_fraction);
    $updated_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $minutes);

    echo $updated_date;
}
```

because in this scenario if minutes is exactly same i.e. 15, 30, 45 or 00 then time fraction would be zero as well, so you need to check time fraction before making a new date

Answer (score 1):

Please try with

```
      $date = "2018-07-16 02:48:30";
      $cons = date('Y-m-d H:',strtotime($date));
      $min = date('i',strtotime($date));
      $min = $min  + 15 - ($min % 15) ;

      if ($min == 60){
          $min = '00';
          $final = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($cons.$min));
          $final = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($final.'1 hour'));
      }else{
          $final = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($cons.$min));
      }

      echo $final;
```

create one function and pass date into that function . function will return pass date with your desire output .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format() method. --> http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

There you can find parameters with which you can access the values of the date you are looking for. Then make a if-clause to check and set the date right. 
Maybe make an array for better structure!

For example:

```
$day  = date_create("2018-07-16 02:15:00");
$dates = array($day); // And so on...
echo $dates[1]->format("H");
// You get the hour in 24h format with like --> 02
// with i you get the minute like --> 15
```

Than you make a switch-Statement or a if-statement and edit the values, not that complicated! 
I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Another example with arrays, which need to be optimized:

```
<?php

$array = [
    '2018-07-16 02:07:30',
    '2018-07-16 02:17:30',
    '2018-07-16 02:37:30',
    '2018-07-16 02:47:30'
];

$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $elem) {
    $time = explode(' ', $elem)[1];
    $date = explode(' ', $elem)[0];
    $timePart = explode(':', $time);
    $minutes = $timePart[1];
    if ($minutes > 1 && $minutes < 15) {
        $newTime = $date . ' ' . $timePart[0] . ':15:' . $timePart[2];
    } else if ($minutes > 15 && $minutes < 30) {
        $newTime = $date . ' ' . $timePart[0] . ':30:' . $timePart[2];
    } else if ($minutes > 30 && $minutes < 45) {
        $newTime = $date . ' ' . $timePart[0] . ':45:' . $timePart[2];
    } else if ($minutes > 45) {
        $newTime = $date . ' ' . $timePart[0] . ':00:' . $timePart[2];
    }

    $newArray[] = $newTime;
}

echo "<pre>"; var_dump($newArray); exit;

?>
```

U can easy convert it to datetime object.

Comment: This is not proper answer for this question .Your code final O/P array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "2018-07-16 02:15:30"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2018-07-16 02:30:30"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "2018-07-16 02:45:30"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "2018-07-16 02:00:30" // MUST BE  2018-07-16 03:00:00
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$dateString = '2018-07-16 02:47:30';

$date = new DateTime($dateString);
$minute = $date->format('i');

switch(true) {
    case $minute <= 15:
        $minute = 15;
        break;
    case $minute <= 30:
        $minute = 30;
        break;
    case $minute <= 45:
        $minute = 45;
        break;
    case $minute <= 60:
        $minute = 60;
        break;
}

$date->setTime($date->format("H"), $minute);

echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change date by following :

```
$date = '2018-07-16 02:07:30';
$justdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$justdate = new DateTime($justdate);
$sdate = date('s', strtotime($date));
$idate = date('i', strtotime($date));
$hdate = date('h', strtotime($date));
$idate = number_format($idate);
if ($idate >= 0 && $idate <= 15) {
    $idate = '15';
    $justdate->setTime($hdate, $idate, $sdate);
    $justdate = $justdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
} else if ($idate >= 16 && $idate <= 30) {
    $idate = '30';
    $justdate->setTime($hdate, $idate, $sdate);
    $justdate = $justdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
} else {
    $hdate = $hdate + 1;
    $idate = '00';
    $sdate = '00';
    $justdate->setTime($hdate, $idate, $sdate);
    $justdate = $justdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
echo $justdate;exit;
```